# How to write console output to a text file with Rscript, like you can with R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, linux

In the past I have used `R CMD BATCH` to execute R code from the command line on a Linux server. The syntax I used was

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore rcode.r output.txt
```

The above code writes console output to `output.txt` which can be monitored as the script is running. Is this also possible with `Rscript`? I would prefer to use `Rscript` since I have heard that `R CMD BATCH` is deprecated.

To clarify my original question, `R CMD BATCH` writes all console output, including messages, warnings, and `print()` statements, to `output.txt`. In contrast `Rscript rcode.r > output.txt` writes only the `print()`ed output to the text file and everything else to the terminal. How can I replicate the behavior of `R CMD BATCH` with `Rscript`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered after some digging that, at least on the Linux system I'm using, `Rscript` is just a convenience function. If you call

`Rscript --verbose foobar.r`

you will see the underlying call is:

```
running
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore --file=foobar.r'
```

This means that `--no-echo` is baked into `Rscript`.

Therefore the solution is to run

`/usr/lib/R/bin/R --no-restore --file=foobar.r > output.txt`

where the `--no-echo` is removed, and the output is redirected to a text file as suggested by @MrFlick. The commands will be echoed in addition to the output.

You can create a new alias for `Rscript` if you want `--no-echo` to be removed by default. For example, in my `.bashrc` file I have the following:

```
function Rscript2() { R --no-restore --file="$1"; }
export -f Rscript2
```

Now, in my Slurm batch job scripts, I can run `Rscript2 file.R` to get the desired behavior: all R console output is included in the `slurm-*.out` files.

Comment: This does not work on my job scheduler, as it just opens an interactive session

Comment: Did you include the file name of the R script in the command? What operating system and job scheduler are you using? @GiulioCentorame

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect the output to a file like you would with any other command line output

```
Rscript rcode.r > output.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to get this to work.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work? Some more details about what exactly happens would be helpful if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Were you able to get around this

Comment: @MrFlick apologies for never responding and late ping. The issue is that `R CMD BATCH` writes all console output, including messages, warnings, and `print()` statements, to `output.txt`. In contrast `Rscript` writes only the `print()`ed output to the text file and everything else to the terminal. How can I replicate the behavior of `R CMD BATCH` with `Rscript`? I will edit the question too.

Comment: The messages are probably going to standard error rather than standard out. What shell are you using to run the command? Usually > just redirects standard out, just whatever alternate version works for your shell to capture all output.